# Whats the node.js server-side code to process the incoming req from phonegap ft.upload?

Tags: node.js, cordova, image-uploading

I have part-developed a hybrid Android app using node.js for my server and javascript, jquery, phonegap (now called cordova 1.6.0) for the app.

Part of the app allows the user to take a photo using the smartphone camera and then upload it to the server.

My code in the app that uploads the image is...

```
    var imageURI = document.getElementById('display_image').src;
    if (!imageURI) { // || (self.elem.image_play.style.display == "none")) {
        console.log('no image uri defined - ' + JSON.stringify(imageURI));
        //document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Take picture or select picture from library first.";
        return;
    }

    // Verify server has been entered
    server = 'http://192.168.1.3:8180/newimage/';
    if (server) {
        console.log("starting upload");
        // Specify transfer options
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        // Transfer picture to server
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {
            console.log("upload successful"+r.bytesSent+" bytes uploaded.");
            //document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload successful: "+r.bytesSent+" bytes uploaded.";
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("upload failed - Error Code = "+error.code);
            //document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = "+error.code;
        }, options);
    }
```

This works fine however I can't figure out how to handle the image on the node.js server. Currently my code is:

```
'/newimage/': function(req,res){

    var chunks;

    req.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('in data processing');
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    req.addListener('end', function () {
        console.log('completing data processing');
        fs.writeFile("out.jpg", chunks, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```

This server method executes but neither of the console.log lines execute.

I have been trying for 2 days to sort this out and I have tried many different ways but I can't figure it out how to process the incoming image file from the phonegap ft.upload method. Can anybody help with this?

Once I have this sorted, my final aim is to upload the image file to amazon s3 storage which I guess I can use knox module for.

Comment: How does the file looks like? It is possible, that the upload will be transferred as multipart request. In that case there will be some boundry headers be appended. (But I don''t think so). Try it with a non image file. I can remember a bug in cordiva, that made it impossible to transfer objects with a media:// url to a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the node formidable and fs modules to write the uploaded image to a /tmp folder on the nodejs server to do OCR later. Code is based on image upload example from the [www.nodebeginner.org](http://www.nodebeginner.org) book.

My JS code in phonegap project in the uploadPicture() method :

```
 // Specify transfer options
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg"
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        // Transfer picture to server
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload successful: "+r.bytesSent+" bytes uploaded.";              
        }, function(error) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = "+error.code;               
        }, options, true);
```

My code in requesthandler.js on the node server :

```
function upload(response, request) {
    console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files) {

        //logs the file information 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(files))

        fs.rename(files.file.path, "/tmp/test.png", function(err) {
            if (err) {
                fs.unlink("/tmp/test.png");
                fs.rename(files.file.path, "/tmp/test.png");
            }
        });
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write("received image:<br/>");
        response.write("<img src='/show' />");
        response.end();
    });
}
```